# convert string to json replace special character before convert

Tags: java

I work with java .

I want to convert String to json

I have this code :

```
String val="[{\"p_emp\":20,\"p_val_error\":0,\"p_val_error_text\":test name : is owner}]";

 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(val);
```

When I test I have this error :

```
 Exception org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 85 [character 86 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:507)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:271)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:431)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:125)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:162)
    at com.dq.taysir.Test.main(Test.java:27)
```

the problem is in **" test name : is owner "**

I want to replace all special character that appear after **p_val_error_text**

this is an example of code that replace all special character

```
String name = name.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%!.„'":*‚^_¤?<>|@ª{«»§}©®™ ]/g, '').toLowerCase();
```

the special character appear only in **p_val_error_text**

so I want to call it only after **p_val_error_text**

If the string is like this :

```
String val="[{\"p_emp\":20,\"p_val_error\":0,\"p_val_error_text\":test name  is owner}]";
```

it can be converted to json so just remove the character `:` in

**test name : is owner**

can someone help me to solve this problem

**Updated :**

this code is working .

```
String val="[{\"p_emp\":20,\"p_val_error\":0,\"p_val_error_text\":test name  is owner}]";



JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(val);
        
        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            
          System.out.println("p_emp  :"+String.valueOf(obj.getInt("p_emp")) );
            
         System.out.println("p_val_error_text  :"+String.valueOf(obj.getString("p_val_error_text")) );
            
            
            System.out.println("p_val_error  :"+String.valueOf(obj.getInt("p_val_error")) );

          
        }
```

but when the string is like this :

```
  String val="[{\"p_emp\":20,\"p_val_error\":0,\"p_val_error_text\":test name : is owner}]";
```

I have this error :

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 81 [character 82 line 1]
```

the difference between first and second example is :

**test name : is owner**

Comment: Why are you working with invalid JSON?

Comment: in 99 % the value is json but in some case the text after : p_val_error_text  contain special character.

that why I want to convert it to json and after that parsing json to extract data

Comment: The problem isn't the special character, it's the missing quotes around the value.

Comment: the problem is only in : in

test name : is owner

Comment: The last code in your edit, even if it doesn't contain `:`, is still not valid JSON. There must be quotes around `test name  is owner`.

Comment: thank you for your response, I have updated my question but I still have error

Comment: @franco Where is the JSON string coming from and why does it produce invalid JSON syntax? The problem should be fixed at the source.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

Keep in mind the *JSON* would still be invalid.

```java
String s = "p_val_error_text\":";
int x = val.indexOf(s) + s.length();
String a = val.substring(0, x), b = val.substring(x);
b = b.replaceAll("[\\Q&\\/#,+()$~%!.„'\":*‚^_¤?<>|@ª{«»§}©®™ \\E]", "");
val = a + b;
```

Output

```
[{"p_emp":20,"p_val_error":0,"p_val_error_text":testnameisowner]
```

I imagine a more accurate approach would be to just encase the value within quotes.

```java
String s = "p_val_error_text\":";
int x = val.indexOf(s) + s.length(),
    y = val.indexOf('}', x);
String a = val.substring(0, x),
       b = val.substring(x, y),
       c = val.substring(y);
val = "%s\"%s\"%s".formatted(a, b, c);
```

Output

```
[{"p_emp":20,"p_val_error":0,"p_val_error_text":"test name : is owner"}]
```

Alternately, use a *regex pattern*.

```
(?<=\"p_val_error_text\":)[^}]+
```

```java
val = val.replaceAll("(?<=\"p_val_error_text\":)[^}]+", "\"$0\"");
```